# Is this a valid way to prove that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, radicals

Assume $\sqrt 2$ is rational.

$$\sqrt 2= \frac{P}{Q}$$

$$2 = \biggr(\frac{P}{Q}\biggr)^2$$

$$2 = \frac{P^2}{Q^2}$$

$P^2 = 2Q^2$ which is impossible because there doesn't exist a number whose square, nor its double, is equal to any other squares. The conclusion produces a contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Kindly use mathjax for math formatting. You may find tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The last argument should make use of the unique prime factorization of natural numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an incomplete proof at best, since you only claim, but don't prove, that there is no (natural) number $n$ such that $2n^2$ is the square of another (natural) number.

Comment: Proving that (which I know to be true), would the proof be complete and logically consistent?

Comment: As long as that proof doesn't use the fact that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, there is no problem.

Comment: @JaydenRivers That's the hard part of the proof. That's the bit you need to prove in order to convince your teacher that you really know how to prove it.

Comment: I agree with José. An easier way to prove this would be to look at the factors of  $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: I was trying to look for a way to prove it without assuming no common factor for P and Q. But I think the proof for the second part of my question requires that we assume no common factors between P and Q anyway, lending to the fact that its an over-complicated way of going about the general proof.

Comment: does anybody know if this holds for 3 times a square as well?

Answer (score 0):

Assume on the contrary that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number.

$\Rightarrow \exists $ integers $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

$\Rightarrow a=\sqrt{2}b\Rightarrow a^2=2b^2$

Clearly, $2|2b^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $2$ must divide $a^2$.

$2$ is a prime number that divides $a^2$, so it must divide $a$.

Therefore, $a=2m$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

Recall that $a^2=2b^2$, replacing $a$ with $2m$,

we get $(2m)^2=2b^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $4m^2=2b^2$$\Rightarrow$$2m^2=b^2$.

Clearly, $2|2m^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $2$ must divide $b^2$.

$2$ is a prime number that divides $b^2$, so it must divide $b$.

Therefore, $b=2n$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now we have two results; $a=2m$ and $b=2n$, which means $a$ and $b$ have $2$ as a common factor.

This contradicts the original hypothesis that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

$\Rightarrow$ The original assumption that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number must be wrong.

$\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number.